# Calling Web-services With Telstra 3G Connection on iPhone is not working

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am an IOS developer.
In my latest application I am showing a list of videos fetched from my server.
I am using xml based Web-Service to fetch the data of the videos to show on the application.
I am using SOAP Post Method and also HTTP Post method here.
It's working well in every network.
Even when I am using Telstra sim and connect the wi-fi it's working good.
But whenever I switch to Telstra 3G Connection my application is not working any more,it's not getting the data back from the web-services, though other applications like gmail, Facebook is working fine with this Telstra 3G Connection.
Can any one help me to find out why this web-service is not working particularly with Telstra 3G Connection?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Ritz

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why it 'just doesn't work', all I can think of at the moment that it has to do with the method of communication which is apparently different from other apps and not allowed on the Telstra provider. Could you provide more code to see if anything there is wrong? Also you could try using someone else's 3g and see if that works?